# Too few arguments to function Adldap\\Models\\Model: …0 passed, 2 expected

Tags: reactjs, laravel, ldap

I am trying to use Ldap login on my React/laravel application. Now I am getting the error 'Too few arguments to function Adldap\Models\Model::__construct(), 0 passed in /.../LdapUserRepository.php on line 148'

I don't understand, what arguments is it expecting? Line 148 is 'return new LdapUser();'. Here is the function it's a part of:

```
  public function createModel(): Model
    {
        // If the model is already an instance of LdapUser, return it.
        if ($this->model instanceof LdapUser) {
            return $this->model;
        }

        // Otherwise, create a new instance.
        return new LdapUser();   // This is line 148
    }
```

And my LdapUser class is declared as 'class LdapUser extends Model', and doesn't expect any arguments. Where is my issue?

I followed the Ldap Documentation, but the authentication of the user isn't working.

Comment: it seems like you probably extend an model similar to this https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2/blob/master/src/Models/Model.php funnily enough this expects 2 parameters :) but it is not specified what packages you are using, that would be nice to know.